# is there a way how to explore bitcoin blockchain

Tags: full-node, python, blockchain-explorer

if I want to explore bitcoin blockchain for instance get address' information, transactions, and so on. what is the right place where I can grab this info. I tried https://blockchain.info but they blocked me because too many requests. Maybe somebody can explain me or point me where I can read the answer on my question?
I would prefer python library but I tend to think I have to install kind of node on my PC and read data from there? can somebody advice me ?
if it is wrong place for this question - could somebody pint me right place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How download whole blockchain and preprocess it for analysis?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/110945/how-download-whole-blockchain-and-preprocess-it-for-analysis)

Answer (score 1):

Try out [mempool.space](https://mempool.space).

It's generally recommended to indeed use your own node, where you can run your own block explorer such as mempool.space (also possible as a hidden service). Having you own node means that you don't have to trust anyone which is what bitcoin is about!

If you just want to try out how a node works, I recommend the [learning bitcoin from the command line](https://github.com/BlockchainCommons/Learning-Bitcoin-from-the-Command-Line/) course. You don't need a local node to try this out. They show you how to set up a node as a VPS (virtual private server).

Comment: thx for good point for a start

Answer (score 0):

I’ve suggest you to run your own node and write a pure python parser in order to get the data that you want.  Also you can setup an local block explorer that connect to your node and take the advantages of the API, no limit/restrictions  and start exploring.

Comment: maybe you can suggest (point) to a good place to read how to start the own node ?

Comment: For local query see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/80560/how-does-bitcore-work also for general info about running a node look at https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node